# checkbox inside bootstrap modal fires twice

Tags: jquery

For some reason, the click event associated with a checkbox fires twice when clicking on it, even though the actual "check" and "uncheck" mark that appears in checkbox does not fire twice. I know it is firing twice because when a user clicks on checkbox, it changes the value of a hidden input field next to it:

```
<td>
            <input id="validity_change_143_validity_address" name="validity_change[143][validity_address]" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked">
            <input id="csv_or_active_records_143_validity_address" name="csv_or_active_records[143][validity_address]" type="hidden" value="true">
          </td>
```

I tried many different things to prevent. But nothing works. I am at this point:

```
$( ".invalidAddrTable").on('click', '#validity_change_143_validity_address', function(e){
    console.log(event.target.id+" and "+$(event.target).attr('class'));
    if( e.target.id === 'validity_change_143_validity_address' ) {
        console.log("Why we get here twice?")
        var $input = $(this).next();
        val = ($input.val() === "true") ? false : true;
        $input.val(val);
    }
})
```

WHy is click event called twice?

Comment: Could you, please, provide more code? May be your problem happens because of where you are declaring your binding.

Comment: This is loading in a modal window? Is it destroying the original or cloning it? If it is a clone, you will have two IDs of "validity_change_143_validity_address".

Comment: One reason could be that you registered the event twice. `on` doesn't override an existing event but adds just another callback to the event chain for the given selector. But like Mindastic said you need to provide more code.

Comment: @KeVin I am rendering the form twice but doing it throguh ruby on rails. They should be two distinct tables.

Comment: @KeVin you were right!!!! I was registering the event twice because I had the same javascript loaded in the partial, so for each rendering of the partial, it would reregister the event! Never stick <script></script> tags in an html slice of code, otherwise you risk reregistering your events!!!!